# C - How to hash (create a map) of a user defined type

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I am trying to create a hash table (map/dictionary) in C on a user defined type structure. I have found many examples that use integers or strings as the key, but how would one have a user defined object as the key?

The main example I have been following is [here](https://github.com/jamesroutley/write-a-hash-table)

Lets say I have different structures like:

EDIT: changed the second data structure example to a better example.

```
struct Point {
  double x;
  double y;
};

struct SomePersonInfo {
  char* a_first_name;
  char* a_last_name;
  float age;
  char* address;
};
```

In c++ its easy:

```
#include <map>
std::map< SomePersonInfo, int>;
// Maybe we want to test if some person is in our data base
// Or assign a more complicated structure (personal info/salary/etc.) as the value
```

How would one hash these structs in C? Maybe a better question to ask is how to properly hash...

Or maybe if anyone has any good books/tutorials/articles they know of.

Comment: The functions should take a `char *` pointer and length. When storing the data you use `malloc()` and `memcpy()` to make a copy of the data. Hashing just loops over the bytes.

Comment: And searching uses `memcmp()`.

Comment: I believe that to properly calculate a hash for an object a function would need to know what data to use, in the case of a structure which member to use. If you are thinking of structures, you could have a member that is a function pointer to hash function, that function would be provided by the user.